# Jackson YAML: support for tags

Tags: jackson, yaml

I'm investigating the use of YAML for a somewhat complicated metadata language. One thing that would be of great use is if the YAML parser supported the use of [YAML tags](http://camel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yamlref.html#tags). This would allow people who write documents in this metadata language to indicate when/if they are defining some object with a well-defined schema. For example:

```
set_one: !dset
  bass: tama rockstar 22x16
  snare: ludwig supralight 6.5x15
  tom1: tama rockstar 12x11
  tom2: tama rockstar 16x16
```

The use of the "!dset" tag in the above YAML is an indication, by the author, that the object defined by "set_one" is supposed to define a drumset and should be parsed according to the schema corresponding to "dset". If the object violates one of the constraints of that schema (for example, it does not define a hi-hat) the user would like to see the error at parsing time and not have it result in some, more opaque, runtime error.

I'm parsing the above sample like so:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
  FileInputStream fis = null;

  try
  {
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      JsonNode nodeTree = mapper.readTree(fis);
      examineObject(nodeTree, 0);
  }
  ...
```

When I look at the JsonNode for "set_one" in the debugger, I don't see any trace of the "!dset" tag. I can think of a lot of cool things Jackson could do (e.g. use annotations to associate a Java class with a given tag and automatically deserialize the elements into an instance of that class) but, at a minimum, I need some way of discovering that that node was tagged with "dset". Does anyone know if/how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

A `JsonNode` cannot contain any reference to a YAML tag because there is no such structure in JSON.

Be aware that Jackson is a high-level abstraction over JSON, XML, YAML and the like. What you want to do is YAML-specific - neither JSON nor XML have a direct equivalent of YAML's tag system (XML also has *tags*, but they are something entirely different). Therefore, Jackson is the wrong API to use this advanced YAML feature.

YAML support in Jackson is provided by [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml), which is perfectly able to deal with tags. So you probably want to use SnakeYAML's API instead of Jackson. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers) is an example which, amongst other things, registers and uses a custom tag. Oh, and it is also able to *use annotations to associate a Java class with a given tag and automatically deserialize the elements into an instance of that class*.