# Exclamatory mark in YAML (YAML tag) causing weird behavior when deserialization and reserialization using jackson YAMLMapper

Tags: templates, jackson, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I tried to deserialize and reserialize the following YAML content using Jackson YAMLMapper. But, the tag !ImportValue is missing. Please let me know **how can I retain the YAML tag !ImportValue**.

**Original content:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            KMSMasterKeyID: !ImportValue DefaultCustomerMasterKeyForThisRegionArn
            SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
      BucketName: blahblah.com
```

**After deserialization and reserialization:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            KMSMasterKeyID: DefaultCustomerMasterKeyForThisRegionArn
            SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
      BucketName: blahblah.com
```

Comment: Quote the value you want to preserve. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quote it as it is not a normal string. It's a YAML tag.

Comment: Jackson does not support YAML tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095924/jackson-yaml-support-for-tags

Comment: Ok, Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, during the YAML loading process, tags are eliminated once you load the data into native types. See this diagram from the spec:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaml.org](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/overview2.png))</sub>

This means that if you want to preserve a tag, you should stop loading before the mapping to native data types. Most YAML implementations provide an API for that. Jackson uses SnakeYAML, which does provide this API, but Jackson doesn't expose it. This means that you need to do this directly with SnakeYAML.

You do it like this:

```java
StreamReader sr = /* whatever you want to load */;
Resolver resolver = new Resolver();
Composer composer = new Composer(new ParserImpl(sr), resolver);
Node root = composer.getSingleNode();
```

When you want to write out the YAML again, you do:

```java
DumperOptions do = new DumperOptions();
Serializer serializer = new Serializer(new Emitter(output, do), resolver, do, null);
Writer w = /* whereever you want to write */;
serializer.serialize(root);
```

Mind that you now need to use the `Node` subclasses to travel through your data if you want to change anything.